# How to achieve fitting with arbitrary cost regularization?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, regression, least-squares, regularization

Perhaps the mathematically easiest case of fitting is linear least squares $L_2$ ("sum of squares"). This is so easy we often learn it already in high school or maybe in our first linear algebra class at college.

The last 10-15 years have seen lots of research in fitting with respect to other norms. $L_1$ ("sum of absolute values") being maybe the most famous example.

---

How could we mathematically with the algorithms available for these two norms be able to achieve completely arbitrary minimization?

One example would be the heavily discontinous "non-negative" error.

$$C(x) = \infty \cdot H(-x) + C_p(x)\cdot H(x)$$

For $H$ being the Heaviside step function. Infinite (or numerically suitably "veery large") values whenever $x$ is negative but $C(0) = 0$ some reasonably smooth increasing function $C_p(x)$ for positive $x$.

Such extremely non-linear behaviour must surely be difficult to be able to achieve using only well behaved methods, or might I be mistaken? I am interested in both research references and counter-examples as answers.